# Falla al cargar el cargar el código ESP1, no funciona la comunicación serial

Tags: arduino, esp8266

Tengo un ESP01S, que esta basado en el esp8266.
Cuando lo Flasheo con el modulo funciona bien, me permite configurar con comandos AT, pero cuando cargo el código, la comunicación serial me empieza ha mandar mensaje codificada, he comprobado los baudios todo OK.

Lo programamo con el Arduino IDE el código se carga sin errores.
No si el modulo esta roto o es la configuración de cargar de Arduino IDE.